# Count items into array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got items from my api:

```
  retrievePeople(): void {
    this.peopleService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.peoples = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

`console.log` of data is:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 41, title: "["John Snow","Jan Kowalski","Jan Nowak"]", description: "111", published: false, createdAt: "2020-08-11T08:43:20.000Z", …}
1: {id: 42, title: "["Jan Nowak","Jan Kowalski","Just test"]", description: "112", published: false, createdAt: "2020-08-11T11:14:58.000Z", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And inside of my component.html I got

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let people of peoples; let i = index" [class.active]="i == currentIndex"
    (click)="setActivePeople(people, i)">
    Description: {{ people.description }}
    Number of people: {{ people.title.length }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried just use `.length` but I got number of characters instead of number of people.

I Tried also something like this:

```
this.size = Object.keys(this.peoples[0].title.split(', ')).length;
```

and it shows me correct value for example: 3

But it only for one value I want this to display it in my list.

How should it looks?

Comment: `title` looks like a malformed string - not array.

Comment: Your API produces malformed JSON. title: `"["John Snow","Jan Kowalski","Jan Nowak"]"` should be title: `["John Snow","Jan Kowalski","Jan Nowak"]` Go ahead and have a look at what produces the JSON.

Comment: Your array from the title has a syntax error `"["John Snow","Jan Kowalski","Jan Nowak"]"` truth syntax that is `["John Snow","Jan Kowalski","Jan Nowak"]` you should fix this from backend and when fix that you no need to split for make array for tittle so you can use them easily see this link from [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xp2deu?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title looks like it's sent as a string, not an array. To get its contents, you should parse it first, or, preferably, have a look at your API signature to see if you can send it as an array instead. If that is not possible, this should work instead.

```js
retrievePeople(): void {
    this.peopleService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          data.forEach(people => {
            people.title = JSON.parse(people.title);
          });
          this.peoples = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

To clarify: `JSON.parse('["John Snow"]')` returns `["John Snow"]`